# UGC: Is this possible that the comments to be shared across publications that inherit from the parent publication?

Tags: tridion, ugc

In my scenario, all pages have been created in the "XXX" publication and this publication has 2 child publications “XX1” and “XX2”.

In “XX1” publication, the users are able to comment the post on the page successfully. But when I see in comment section the Tridion, I can only see those comments on child publication page only (By Read only mode option). It does not show in parent publication page.

I would like to share comments on parent publication also from any Child publication page. is it possible?

And the same things vice-versa, if users added any comment in parent publication page then those comments should also display on the child publication page.  Is it also possible?

Answer (score 3):

Community Builder (comments and ratings) is not blueprinting aware. Comments on an item in publication XX1 are only shown when you open that item in that particular publication context.

If you want to show the same comments in 'XX1' and 'XX2', you could configure the front-end logic so that it uses the publication id for 'XXX'. In that case, you could view and moderate the items in Tridion on level XXX, and the comments would be visible on both sites.

A different but superficially similar problem, is that the GUI disallows users to moderate comments on a shared item. This is a known bug. There is a hotfix for it. With this hotfix, you are able to moderate comments even if the page / component is shared (not localized). You should check with SDL customer support if the hotfix is publicly available.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, actually, my problem is little different, Could you please see my updated question again? Thanks again